# Monotone class theorem and measurability of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, monotone-class-theorem

Consider a family $f_i$, $i \in I$, of mappings of a set $\Omega$ into measurable spaces $(E_i,\mathcal{E}_i)$. We assume that for each $i \in I$ there is a subclass $\mathcal{N}_i$ of $\mathcal{E}_i$ , closed under finite intersections and such that $\sigma(\mathcal{N}_i) = \mathcal{E}_i$. Let 
$$
\mathcal{N} := \bigg\{ \bigcap_{j \in J} f_j^{-1}(A_j) \colon A_j \in \mathcal{N}_j, J \subseteq I \text{ finite}\bigg\},
$$
then by the *Monotone Class Theorem* we have $\sigma(\mathcal{N}) = \sigma(f_i \colon i \in I)$. $\qquad$ $(\ast)$

I don't see why $(\ast)$ is an immediate consequence of the *Monotone Class Theorem*, which states the following:

> *Monotone Class Theorem.* Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a collection of subsets of a set $\Omega$ such that
>
> 1. $\Omega \in \mathcal{M}$,
> 2. if $A,B \in \mathcal{M}$ and $A \subseteq B$, then $B \setminus A \in \mathcal{M}$,
> 3. if $\{A_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is an increasing sequence of elements of $\mathcal{M}$, then $\bigcup_{n \geq 1} A_n \in \mathcal{M}$.
>
> If $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{M}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under finite intersections, then $\sigma(\mathcal{F}) \subseteq \mathcal{M}$.

**My attempt of proof of $(\ast)$:** I know that $\sigma(f_i \colon i \in I) = \sigma(\mathcal{G})$, where
$$
\mathcal{G} = \bigcup_{i \in I} f_i^{-1}(\mathcal{N}_i).
$$
At this point we only need that $\sigma(\mathcal{N}_i) = \mathcal{E}_i$ but we don't use that $\mathcal{N}_i$ is closed under finite intersections. Now we want to show $\sigma(\mathcal{N}) = \sigma(\mathcal{G})$. It is clear that $\mathcal{N} \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{G})$ and hence $\sigma(\mathcal{N}) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{G})$. Thus it remains to show that $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{N})$. At this point I got stuck and I don't see how to use the *Monotone Class Theorem*.

Comment: It seems to me that you have skipped over the "hard" part of the argument with the phrase "I know that...", this is where you need the MCT.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I think I already explained why $\mathcal{N}\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{G})$, what remains is $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{N})$.

Comment: But let's forget about my attempt above for a moment. I would like to understand the book, where it says this follows from the Monotone Class Theorem. Can you explain me how to apply it correctly in this setting?

Comment: Before we get to the book's argument, I'd like you to see that ${\cal G}\subseteq {\cal N}$ trivially: every $\cal G$-set belongs to $\cal N$.

Comment: I had written it backwards in my previous comment (now deleted).

Comment: If $B \in \mathcal{G}$, then there is some $i_0$ such that $B = f_{i_0}^{-1}(A_{i_0})$ for some $A_{i_0} \in \mathcal{N}_{i_0}$. Now it is obvious that $B \in \mathcal{N}$.

Answer (score 3):

The result does not need the Monotone Class Theorem, just 
some basic manipulations with $\sigma$-fields. The crucial
lemma is this:

**Lemma:** If $f:\Omega\to E$ is a map, and $\cal C$ a collection
of subsets of $E$, then $\sigma f^{-1}{\cal C}=f^{-1}\sigma\, {\cal C}.$

*Proof.* ($\Rightarrow$) Since ${\cal C}\subseteq \sigma {\cal C}$ we have  $$f^{-1}{\cal C}\subseteq f^{-1}\sigma {\cal C}.\tag1$$
Since $f^{-1}\sigma {\cal C}$ is a $\sigma$-field (check this!) generating $\sigma$-fields 
on both sides of (1) gives $\sigma f^{-1}{\cal C}\subseteq f^{-1}\sigma {\cal C}.$

($\Leftarrow$) Since $f^{-1}{\cal C}\subseteq \sigma f^{-1}{\cal C}$
we have $${\cal C}\subseteq {\cal C}^\prime\tag2$$
where ${\cal C}^\prime=\{B\subseteq E: f^{-1}B\in \sigma f^{-1}{\cal C}\}$.
Now ${\cal C}^\prime$ is $\sigma$-field (check this!), so when we generate 
$\sigma$-fields on both sides of (2) we get $\sigma {\cal C}\subseteq {\cal C}^\prime$, and hence $f^{-1}\sigma {\cal C}\subseteq \sigma f^{-1}{\cal C}.$

---

For fixed $i\in I$ we have ${\cal N}\supseteq f_i^{-1}{\cal N}_i.$ 
Generating $\sigma$-fields on both sides and applying the lemma
 gives 
$$\sigma({\cal N})\supseteq \sigma f^{-1}_i{\cal N}_i =f_i^{-1}\sigma {\cal N}_i=f^{-1}_i{\cal E}_i=\sigma(f_i).$$

This is true for every $i$, so 
$$\sigma({\cal N})\supseteq \sigma(f_i, i\in I).$$ 
The other inclusion is trivial (check this!) and so 
$$\sigma({\cal N}) =\sigma(f_i, i\in I).$$